# Fragment inside a viewpager ignores tabs height when inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created a viewpager using a fragment adapter which returns a few fragments
however the layout is not taking into acount the tabs height and results in cut and missing items for lower part of the screen (the fragment layout).

i.e it has a toolbar or a button which suppose to show at the bottom of the layout it will look okay in the layout editing tool which shows only the fragment but once inside the pager it will ignore the height of the tabs keep thinking the layout takes the entire screen resulting in the lower part not showing properly (only the higher part of the button is shown)

How can i make it to take into account the height of the tabs in the activity?
the inflation code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,container,false);
        return view;
    }
```

the viewpager layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/l_acs_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/l_acs_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/l_acs_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

a sample fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/l_f_cscp_label_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ChooseImage:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/l_f_cscp_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_picture_512" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/l_f_cscp_fab_imageButton"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_circle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24px" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. If the entire layout of your fragment is not visible, you can make the button stick at the bottom of your screen and make the other parts of the layout scrollable.

Comment: This is happening for me only when the keyboard is open and the items that should appear at the bottom are more than half the height of the screen. So whenever their height is less they appear correctly even when the keyboard is open.